# Email Reminder for multiple Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to send email reminder if the date columns is 7 or 1 days away from today. I have already made the script and what i want to add is it should consider others columns too, not only 1 with one script, for sending reminder for respective columns.

For eg:
It should remind for Plan Date, Plan Date 1, Plan Date 2 and Plan Date 3.

Please see the [Sample Attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o83cQK1R1V2LNdwCTZZjxLDJIZjBmvPod0s0UcIVQyU/edit#gid=0).

Script:

```
function checkReminder() {
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// figure out what the last column is
var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();

// the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
// is the headers, so start with row 2
var startRow = 2;

// the columns are indexed starting at 2, and the first column
// is the headers, so start with column 2
var startCol = 2;

// grab column 3 (the 'days left' column) 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,3,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the reminder name column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the first row
range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lastCol-startCol+1, 1);
var column_info_values = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop over the days left values
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
if(days_left == 1) {
  // if it's exactly 1, do something with the data.
  var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];
  var column_name = column_info_values[0][0];

  msg = msg + "Reminder: "+reminder_name+" - "+column_name+" is due in "+days_left+" day.\n";
  warning_count++;
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
if(days_left == 7) {
  // if it's exactly 7, do something with the data.
  var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];
  var column_name = column_info_values[0][0];

  msg = msg + "Reminder: "+reminder_name+" - "+column_name+" is due in "+days_left+" days.\n";
  warning_count++;
}
}

 if(warning_count) {
MailApp.sendEmail("myidsample@gmail.com", 
    "Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
}

};
```

Comment: Is this script working fine for 1 column ?

Comment: Yes, its working for B and C column

Comment: Ok, I have answered it.

Comment: Facing a little issue on same, kindly confirm my request !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're currently fetching only single column and processing that only.
In order to make this script run over other columns too, you'll need to loop through them, fetch data and then process them one by one.

Here you're fetching data from 3rd column :

```
// grab column 3 (the 'days left' column) 
var range = sheet.getRange(2,3,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();
```

Like wise you can run a loop till last column and fetch data from 3rd, 5th, 7th .. columns and keep processing them.

So the code goes like this

```
function checkReminder() {
    // get the spreadsheet object
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // fetch this sheet
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

    // figure out what the last row is
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    // figure out what the last column is
    var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();

    // the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
    // is the headers, so start with row 2
    var startRow = 2;

    // the columns are indexed starting at 2, and the first column
    // is the headers, so start with column 2
    var startCol = 2;

    // Now, grab the reminder name column
    range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - startRow + 1, 1);
    var reminder_info_values = range.getValues();

    // Now, grab the first row
    range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lastCol - startCol + 1, 1);
    var column_info_values = range.getValues();

    var warning_count = 0;
    var msg = "";

    for (var u = 3; u <= lastCol; u += 2) {
        // grab the day's left column
        var range = sheet.getRange(2, u, lastRow - startRow + 1, 1);
        var numRows = range.getNumRows();
        var days_left_values = range.getValues();

        // Loop over the days left values
        for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
            var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
            if (days_left == 1) {
                // if it's exactly 1, do something with the data.
                var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];
                var column_name = column_info_values[0][0];

                msg = msg + "Reminder: " + reminder_name + " - " + column_name + " is due in " + days_left + " day.\n";
                warning_count++;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
            var days_left = days_left_values[i][0];
            if (days_left == 7) {
                // if it's exactly 7, do something with the data.
                var reminder_name = reminder_info_values[i][0];
                var column_name = column_info_values[0][0];

                msg = msg + "Reminder: " + reminder_name + " - " + column_name + " is due in " + days_left + " days.\n";
                warning_count++;
            }
        }

        if (warning_count) {
            MailApp.sendEmail("myidsample@gmail.com",
                "Reminder Spreadsheet Message", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

This is un-tested code, let me know if any issue arises. I'll be happy to help you.

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it did worked well for others columns, however, i am getting multiple email at the same time for the same reminder name. Also, i want the column name to be changed as per date column as Plan Date 1, Plan date 2, Plan date 3 and so on (Now, it is mentioning "Plan date" only).

Comment: Can you show me your sample ? Without seeing that it's hard to understand your issue remotely.

Comment: The link of sample is same mentioned above:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o83cQK1R1V2LNdwCTZZjxLDJIZjBmvPod0s0UcIVQyU/edit#gid=0

Here, I have to get the email reminder as:

Reminder: DOT Renewal - Plan Date is due in 7 day.

Reminder: DOT - Plan Date 2 is due in 7 day.

Reminder: DOT - Plan Date 3 is due in 1 day.

Reminder: Annual General Meeting/CRO - Plan Date 1 is due in 7 days.

Reminder: DOT Renewal - Plan Date 1 is due in 1 day.

Reminder: Annual General Meeting/CRO - Plan Date 3 is due in 7 days.

Please correct the email reminder script.
Thanks!!